# window.setTimeout('window.location="http://www.example.com"; ', 2000); in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i want to make this script in code behind because to change the url dynamically

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.setTimeout('window.location="http://www.example.com"; ', 2000);
 </script>
```

and i have tried this but not working

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "closePage", "window.setTimeout('window.location='http://www.example.com';',5000)", true);
```

can any one tell how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

100% working and Tested

You Need to Use `@` for Escape Sequence and Some Changes as below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"window.setTimeout('window.location=\'http://www.example.com\',5000');", true);
```